# Buscar Somente os números de uma String usando Regex em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Estou tentando limpar uma coluna de um dataset de processos e os número dos processos vêm em várias formas:

```
5080847-62.2018.4.04.7100
033/2.17.0001000-7
```

Quero deixar somente números e remover os outros caracteres, Já tentei utilizando `r"[\d+]"` mas só retorna os primeiros números antes de qualquer caractere e o restante é excluído.

Answer (score 4):

```
import re
proc = " 5080847-62.2018.4.04.7100 033/2.17.0001000-7"
numeros = "".join(re.findall("\d+", proc))
print(numeros)
```

Partes de uma expressão regular acham "blocos" do texto que você quer- se usar "d+", vai estar buscando por um "bloco de dígitos com pelo menos um dígito". em vez disso, faço a expressão regular achar os blocos de dígits, mas com o método "findall" ele volta todos os matches na string- no caso, todos os dígitos. A chamada a `"".join` cola todos essas sequências de volta em uma única string.

Também é possível fazer um filtro de caracteres com a sintaxe de "generator expression" - nesse caso, expressões regulares nem são necessárias (o que acaba sendo um problema a menos):

```
proc = " 5080847-62.2018.4.04.7100 033/2.17.0001000-7"
numeros = "".join(char for char in proc if char.isdigit())
print(numeros)
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html#negated) `\D` (qualquer coisa que **não** seja um dígito), e removê-los da string:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'\D')

print(r.sub('', '5080847-62.2018.4.04.7100')) # 50808476220184047100
print(r.sub('', '033/2.17.0001000-7')) # 03321700010007
```

O [método `sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.sub) troca os trechos que correspondem à regex por `''` (string vazia). Na prática, é o mesmo que remover todos os `\D`. A saída é:

```
50808476220184047100
03321700010007
```

---

Se os números estão na mesma string, você pode usar uma [classe de caracteres negada](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) para evitar que os espaços sejam substituídos:

```
r = re.compile(r'[^\d ]')

print(r.sub('', '5080847-62.2018.4.04.7100 033/2.17.0001000-7'))
```

Agora a regex é `[^\d ]` (qualquer coisa que não seja `\d` ou espaço - o `[^` indica que eu quero qualquer coisa que **não** esteja dentro dos colchetes). Note que há um espaço antes do `]`, pois ele faz parte do que eu não quero que seja substituído.

Assim, os dígitos e espaços são preservados, e todo o resto é removido. O resultado é:

```
50808476220184047100 03321700010007
```

---

Obs: o atalho `\d` corresponde a qualquer caractere da [categoria Unicode "Number, Decimal Digit"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm). Isto inclui não apenas os dígitos de 0 a 9, mas também vários outros caracteres que representam dígitos, como por exemplo o `٢` ([ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT TWO](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0662/index.htm)), [entre outros](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm).

Então, por *default*, `\d` inclui esses caracteres, e `\D` não. Se seus dados não contém tais caracteres, não há problema. Mas se quiser ser mais específico e considerar apenas os dígitos de 0 a 9, você pode usar a [*flag* ASCII](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.ASCII), ou então usar `[0-9]` em vez de `\d`, e `[^0-9]` em vez de `\D`:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'\D')
print(r.sub('', '12-34.٢٤٨')) # 1234٢٤٨

r = re.compile(r'\D', re.ASCII)
print(r.sub('', '12-34.٢٤٨')) # 1234

r = re.compile(r'[^0-9]')
print(r.sub('', '12-34.٢٤٨')) # 1234
```

Comment: Olá, primeiramente obrigada pela dica.

Comment: Preciso aplicar essa regra em uma coluna inteira, cada linha contendo um número diferente. Alguma sugestão? Obrigada.

Comment: @AnaCarolinaPimenta Seria isso: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/replace-values-in-pandas-dataframe-using-regex/ ?